# URLSearchParams returns empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I want to get search `params` and add `params` to URL, but getting empty array every time.

Example url - `http://localhost:3000/buildings?search_query=test&page=2`

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  const params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
  console.log(params); //Getting empty object {}
}
```

Comment: Log `this.props.location.search` to make sure it contains what you expect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try

```
 console.log(params.get("page"));
```

It should return '2'.
The URLSearchParams is displayed as an empty object in the console and does not display all the values.
It does allow you to call a get function though.

Otherwise make sure the this.props.location.search does have an valid function.

```
new URL("http://localhost:3000/buildings?search_query=test&page=2").search
```

Does return a valid value for example.

Answer (score 9):

Turns out when you do this in the chrome dev console it returns an empty object to the console instead of the standard way it shows an object with multiple keys

```
params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
```

You would expect it show an object with keys when you log out params but it does not. In order to actually see them in the console you need to iterate through it with a loop

```
for (let item of params) {
  console.log('item: ', item)
}
```

Pretty confusing since I was expected it to work like a normal object

Comment: Lol - this was the answer and agree, confusing as heck. Is this a bug or any specific reason behind this?

Answer (score 4):

I guess that you use react-router and append URL query string to `/buildings`. So `this.props.location.search` is empty.

```
history.push({
  pathname: '/buildings?search_query=test&page=2',
});
```

Please set up URL query string in `search` property.

```
history.push({
  pathname: '/buildings',
  search: '?search_query=test&page=2'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to show the params:

```
for (let param of params) {
  console.log(param);
}
```

This will show in the console all of the params. Also you should check the examples in this page, I think they would help you!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Answer (score 1):

`URLSearchParams` are iterable, so you can also do `[...params]` to get an array of key-value pairs.